# How to introduce new line in node js

Tags: node.js

actually i have a string which already consist newline break ( \n ) but it seems it doesn't working when i print that string in html page. Currently till now i tried it this, but it simply remove \n but doesn't introducing newline.

```
var os = require('os');
items['body'] = items['body'].replace(/\\n/g, os.EOL+os.EOL);
```

just simply items['body'] = "you \n there"
and after applying above code it simply print ( you there )
but what i want  to print is ( you in one line ) and (there in another line )

Comment: `you <br /> there` ?

Comment: it simply print <br /> not introducing new line

Comment: You need to show all of your code.